# Can not receive DHCP request from different VLAN

Tags: cisco, vlan, dhcp, packet-tracer

[image]

I've been faced with this. I've set up a DHCP pool at the server with the following configuration:

```
pool-vlan20
default gateway: 192.168.2.1
start ip: 192.168.2.100
```

The router has been set up as the following:

```
int fa0/0
no shut
ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
ip helper-address 192.168.1.100
exit
int fa0/0.1
encapsulation dot1Q 10
ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
ip helper-address 192.168.1.100
exit
int fa0/0.2
encapsulation dot1Q 20
ip address 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0
ip helper-address 192.168.1.100
exit
```

But I still don't get the DHCP on PC4. Anything that I missed?

Comment: I assume your dhcp server is on 192.168.1.100? Check that you don't have a 'no service dhcp' on your router. a "no service dhcp" block dhcp helper...

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1**

First and foremost, you need to ensure that you turn on DHCP service on DHCP Server:

[image]

Then check the following things:

- Router2 can ping DHCP Server 192.168.1.100.
- VLAN 10 and 20 are created on both switches and trunked properly between Switch-Switch and Switch-Router

If those points are satisfied, your PC should receive IP address.

**2**

Other things you should consider are:

- On Router2, you should NOT configure IP address of interface fa0/0. Just configure IP address for its subinterfaces.
- Your subinterface numbers should match the VLAN numbers. For example, you should use fa0/0.10 for VLAN 10 and fa0/0.20 for VLAN 20.

I hope it is helpful and you can solve this issue.

Comment: Might be useful to set a static IP address on the PC and check if it can ping the server.

Comment: I don't think the subinterface has to match the vlan number (even if it's a best practice)...  It's the case for SVI on catalyst switches but on router...

Comment: @Golgot "should" is different than "has to", and I believe I used the first word. It may not be your best pratice, but mine (at least). It is an ugly mess when using subinterface .123 for VLAN 765, and so on.

Comment: @HungTran, no offense at all, this is also my way to do and I just didn't pay attention that this was a suggestion - which is good indeed! Sorry!